# Retrieving Formulas enclosed within Excel concat function

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula, concatenation

I want to parse an excel concat function to find the result of the enclosed expression. Eg: `=CONCAT("=1-2-3+7*8")` should return 52, and `=CONCAT("=AVERAGE(A1,A2)")` should return the average of the two cells.

I've tried pasting as value, but that doesn't work unless we explicitly enter the cell and press enter. 
Is there a function or any other way to accomplish this in excel?

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about your end goal, cause right now, concat has no added value and `=CONCAT(AVERAGE(A1,A2))` does what you are trying to do. However it would be the same as `=AVERAGE(A1,A2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function raghav(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim s As String

    s = Mid(rng(1).Formula, 2)
    arr = Split(s, Chr(34))
    For Each a In arr
        If Left(a, 1) = "=" Then
            raghav = Evaluate(a)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```